# Start a fragment from MainActivity that calls another fragment. The listener returns to the MainActivity

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

My MainActivity(1) implements FragmentStatePagerAdapter, with SectionPagerAdapter and ViewPager. It works OK, apart from the problem I have to call getItemPosition to update one of the Fragments, which causes the whole thing to be recreated. Anyway...

One of the "tabs", calls a Fragment(2=BaixarOrcamentoFragment.java), which in turn, calls another Fragment(3=FillReasonToBaixaFragment.java), so the user can insert a text.
Fragment(2) implements THE LISTENER that Fragment(3) uses to return a "text value", so Fragment(2) can continue and finish it's tasks.
Here is the code in Fragment(2), that calls Fragment(3):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                FillReasonToBaixaFragment fillFragment = new
                                    FillReasonToBaixaFragment();
                                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                args.putInt("ORCID", baixarModelList.get(masterPosition)
                                                                    .getOrcGroupID());

                                fillFragment.setArguments(args);
                                fillFragment.show(fragmentManager, FILL_REASON_TO_BAIXA);
```

Then, Fragment(3) gets the bundle ORCID,stars the listener, get some data, shows a text input, and finishes by sending this "text" to the interface:

```
BaixaItemdoOrcamentoListener listener = (BaixaItemdoOrcamentoListener) this
            .getContext();
```

..and then returning what has collected (text) using this interface (listener):

```
 public interface BaixaItemdoOrcamentoListener
{
    void OnFinishedFillReason(String mEditext);
}
```

However, it's not returning back to Fragment(2), which called Fragment(3), where I implemented the method to receive this returning value:

```
  @Override
public void OnFinishedFillReason(String mEditext)
{}
```

It shows a cast error, saying that **.MainActivity cannot be cast to .FillReasonToBaixaFragment$BaixaItemdoOrcamentoListener**

I went on and DECLARED the OnFinishedFillReason inside the MainActivity, which implements FillReasonToBaixaFragment.BaixaItemdoOrcamentoListener.

**Be aware now, that the actual implementation of the tasks are in Fragment(2).**

Guess what: when I enter the text in Fragment(3) and press  ( android:imeOptions="actionDone"), it returns to the MainActivity, NOT to the Fragment(2), the one that has called Fragment(3).

MainActivity doesn't know the existence of any of the the Views inside Fragment(2), a priori, which will, in turn, update all these views ONCE received the "text" from Fragment(3).

Perhaps I didn't search thoroughly, but I couldn't find anything that resembles this situation.

How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Afternoon everyone.
I figured it out how to make this happen.
First: I removed OnFinishedFillReason interface from Fragment(2), and therefore, from Fragment(3).
In Fragment(2), I started the Fragment(3) like this, setting a *setTargetFragment*:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                FillReasonToBaixaFragment fillFragment = new
                                    FillReasonToBaixaFragment();
                                fillFragment.setTargetFragment(BaixaOrcamentoFragment.this,
                                                               FILL_REASON_TO_BAIXA);
                                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                args.putInt("ORCID", baixarModelList.get(masterPosition)
                                                                    .getOrcGroupID());

                                fillFragment.setArguments(args);
                                fillFragment.show(fragmentManager,
                                                  this.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

The target fragment is the Fragment(2) itself.
Then I added in Fragment(2):

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == FILL_REASON_TO_BAIXA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {// code in here }
```

In Fragment(3), I added in the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method, the following:

```
 targetFragment = getTargetFragment();
    if (targetFragment instanceof BaixaOrcamentoFragment)
    {
        orcID = getArguments().getInt("ORCID");
    }
```

At the end of the returning elements, like this:

```
Intent returnData = new Intent();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();            
            bundle.putString("EDITTEXT", txtEdited);
            returnData.putExtras(bundle);
            targetFragment.onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, returnData);
            this.dismiss();
            return true;
```

And then, inside the *onActivityResult* I collected the data, like this:

```
 Bundle returnedValues = data.getExtras();
        String mRazao = returnedValues.getString("EDITTEXT").trim();
```

And that was it.

But I still have a problem: I have 6 tabs. Tab 4 is never selected as currentItem, inside the method below:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position)
{
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```